# How can I convert an array into an ListIterator?

Tags: java, arrays, list, listiterator

I have an array of reference type. I want to use `hasPrevious()` and `hasNext()` methods. 
I want to use `ListIterator`.
Is it the right way to convert an array into an `ListIterator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this is to turn the array into a `List`.
The following code is using way of `hasPrevious()`

```
Object[] objArray = { new Object(), new Object() };
ListIterator<Object> listIterator = Arrays.asList(objArray).listIterator(objArray.length);
while (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
    Object object = listIterator.previous();
    System.out.println(object.toString());
}
```